# App crashes when chooseing activity

Tags: android

I know I could Just manually set this up but I should be able to use a array, but I keep getting a crash, I am thinking it is something simple nut I just cannot find the issue, the crash occurs once a button is pressed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eric.theworks"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.eric.theworks.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Numbers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NUMBERS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InternalStore"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INTERNALSTORE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Reading"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.READING" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> `public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
String activities[] = { "ST", "SETTINGS", "INTERNALSTORE", "READING" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = v.getId();
    for (int i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
        if (id == getResources().getIdentifier("b" + i, "id",
                "com.eric.theworks")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.eric.theworks." + activities[i]);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

}`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Passing Data" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Internal Storage"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Reading Data"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Ok logcat:

```
03-17 05:36:20.542: D/libEGL(20653): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-17 05:36:20.550: D/libEGL(20653): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-17 05:36:20.558: D/libEGL(20653): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
03-17 05:36:20.652: D/OpenGLRenderer(20653): Enabling debug mode 0
03-17 05:36:23.987: D/AndroidRuntime(20653): Shutting down VM
03-17 05:36:23.987: W/dalvikvm(20653): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fb4300)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    ... 11 more
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.eric.theworks.ST }
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.eric.theworks.Menu.onClick(Menu.java:28)
03-17 05:36:23.995: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    ... 14 more
03-17 05:36:25.519: I/Process(20653): Sending signal. PID: 20653 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Here is the menu.java idk why it will not show up: http://pastebin.com/pJ1LNtY3

Comment: From logcat: 03-17 05:10:32.300: E/AndroidRuntime(19878): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: So maybe post full stack trace

Comment: It's very clear. `Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.eric.theworks.ST }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess without seeing the logcat, but probably the exception you're getting is an `ActivityNotFoundException`. In your manifest, your `Activities` respond to actions whose names start with `"android.intent.action"`, and in code you're initiating actions with names starting with `"com.eric.theworks."`. I'd recommend you changing actions described in manifest to the `"com.eric.theworks."` variant, cause using default Android naming for custom actions is not a good thing to do. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @EricMiller, What exactly?

Comment: Now only the reading activity is failing.: 03-17 05:50:32.519: E/AndroidRuntime(20957): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eric.theworks/com.eric.theworks.Reading}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

Comment: Well I guess this is a different question :)

Comment: And actully it was cast as a spinner, and this is why you dont code at 6 am without sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its the code in your activities rather than the manifest or layouts. Check your logcat logs and the exception that is crashing your app is shown and will give you information what is wrong.

Comment: I know, weird thing when I edit my code I see my code that is missing but for some reason it is not showing up